# Background image full width, limited height

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a background-image effect, similar to on http://yipit.com/.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div id="landing-header">
    <img class="landing-background" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/new/landing-background.jpg"/>
</div>

#landing-header {
    height: 489px;
}
.landing-background {
    height: auto;
    min-width: 1460px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is that the horizontal width is always as wide as the browser and the image scales accordingly. For example, if it is a `500x200` image and the browser is `1000px` wide, the image would scale to `1000x400`. This is working.

However, I only want the container to be `400 px` high. In other words, I want to cut off the image at `400px`. For example, the image in a `2000px` browser width would be `2000x800`, but only the top `400px` would show. How would I accomplisht this?

Note that I **only** want the image to resize when the width of the browser is larger than the width of the image, I don't want the image to resize every single time the browser is changed.

Comment: maybe just add overflow: hidden; to #landing-header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you can achieve your desired results through **CSS3 Property** `background-size:cover;`

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

see the demo :- http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

**UPDATED**

see  the updated demo its a very small image rather than the width of browser so its covering the whole background :- http://tinkerbin.com/CraP8wBh

Comment: Thank you -- this seems to resize it whenever the browser is resized, which is a bit annoying. I only want it to resize when the width of the browser is wider than the width of the image. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: no, what I'm saying is if you adjust the height of the browser (and not the width), nothing should happen. In your code using cover, this is not the case.

Comment: oh alright so than you achieve your results through position:absolute property.....with fix height with 100% width....

Comment: ok thank you, could you please show in your answer how that would be done and I'll accept it